# How would one allow collisions between a spawned Sprite and the rest of the World?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocos2d-iphone

Hey I'm writing my first iPhone game in swift and I'm trying to make it so a sprite I spawn in from a .png has physics. I add it to the physicsNode but when I run it nothing collides with it.

Here's my code:

```
let platform = CCSprite(imageNamed: segName)

    platform.position = location
    platform.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    let rotate = CCActionRotateBy(duration: t, angle: angleFloat)
    platform.runAction(rotate)
    gamePhysicsNode.addChild(platform)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you've provided it doesn't look like you've attached the sprite to a [physicsbody](http://cocos2d.spritebuilder.com/docs/api/Classes/CCPhysicsBody.html)? A sprite/node doesn't have one by default, so, simply adding it to a physicsNode will just render it as a simple sprite without any physical attributes = no collisions or anything like that.

A tip: Spritebuilder is great for setting physicsbodies because it allows you to edit the shape visually, so that you easily can match it to the shape of your sprite.